# WCF Service Failing With Method Not Allowed

Tags: jquery, wcf

I have a JSON WCF service and I have written some javascript to access the service like this,

```
function stuffClick2() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.54.98/JsonWCFService/Service1.svc/Post",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: '{"x":"1","y":"2","message":"The answer is: "}',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) { $('body').html(data); }     
        });
    }
```

I have written an HTML page which has the above javascript in it. The HTML page is served up using IIS.

When I access the HTML page using chrome on my PC I see these operations being sent to the WCF JSON service in this order,

```
OPTIONS /JsonWCFService/Service1.svc/Post HTTP/1.1
POST /JsonWCFService/Service1.svc/Post HTTP/1.1
```

The OPTIONS was previously failing, but I made the OPTIONS call return this header which then makes it work,

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

But the callback I have defined above does not work,

```
success: function(data) { $('body').html(data); }
```

I know that the WCF service has returned something like this,

```
<b> The answer is 3 </b>
```

But when the callback is called the value of data is an empty string.

When I run the html page in a different browser (IE) which only causes a POST call, but not an OPTIONS call then it works. I notice that IE warns me that it poses a security risk and asks me whether I want to continue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran across this issue when I was trying to implement CORS with WCF for a mobile HTML app I was making. OPTIONS is a preflight request to see if a method is available before calling it.

Here will be your problems:

1. OPTIONS is, I think, defaultly turned off by IIS. Possibly a starting point is here: http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/cors-and-iis
2. The OPTIONS verb will make it to your actual POST method so you will want to have something in WCF filter OPTIONS to another method with the same return type that does nothing. And filter the POST verb to your actual method. If you don't do this, you will find strange behavior of either your method being called twice or it will throw a webservice vague exception.

Im not sure if you are using CORS or not, but the principal will be the same, as it sends a OPTIONS request then a POST request.

Comment: You are on the right track, but it it weird because it was all working for me earlier in the day.

Comment: OK, so I have got the options thing working (by adding some code in the Application_BeginRequest method to return the headers that the OPTIONS is requesting). So the post then occurs after that, but I get an error from XMLHttpRequest - origin null is not allowed. So it seems like the header it is using in the post is 'Origin: null' I can see it in fiddler. Why is this?

Comment: If I look at the post operations that work there is no origin header specified. which explains why it works.

Comment: I think it relates to the way I am using the jquery, I am accessing the html file including the jquery like this in chrome. 'file://C:/Users/petermc/workspace/HelloPhoneGap/assets/www/index.html' I will try and serve it up using IIS.

Comment: OK, it is working better now, in IE at least if I serve the jquery html page in IIS. Anyway it appears that this is not an issue for me as I am only testing using a browser. The actual application will be inside an android app compiled using PhoneGap, which will make it a native app which will change this particular behavior.

Comment: Phonegap still hosts your content in a webbrowser, (some variant of chrome I believe). I recommend you get it to work in chrome. If it doesn't in chrome then I would put my money on it not working for you in phonegap for android. Are you trying to use CORS to go cross domain with ajax? An origin can be specified if you are in your header. See here: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: OK, thanks I will look into it more. It does work with phonegap now though, my app on Android connects to the service no problem. But I shouldn't just forget about it because what phonegap is doing is not visible to me so I cannot really be too sure what it is doing.

Comment: I have updated the question above because I have got around the OPTIONS problem, but I don't understand why the callback ends up with an empty result.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks your answer did put me on a path of solving the problem.

When I was accessing the HTML page with the ajax javascript in it I was using,

```
http://localhost/file.html
```

But if you look at the javascript it is accessing the WCF service using,

```
http://192.168.54.98/JsonWCFService/Service1.svc/Post
```

If I make them both

```
http://mymachinename.domain.com/JsonWCFService/Service1.svc/Post
http://mymachinename.domain.com/file.html
```

Then it works without having to call an OPTIONS operation.

That doesn't explain why an OPTIONS and then a POST from chrome doesn't work. Chrome just seems to ignore the results.